# IOException issue with asynchronous PDF creation

Tags: vb.net, pdf, asynchronous, io

I have an asynchronous method that creates a PDF file from XML retrieved from a database.  Everything works great, but occasionally I get an `IOException` because when I try to cleanup the temporary `.fo` file after creating the PDF, the file is still in use.

```
Public Sub FormatObjectToPdf(ByVal intRxNo As Integer, ByVal strSourceFileName As String)
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim strPdfFile As String = g_strRootPath & "Paperwork\" & intRxNo & "M.pdf"

    ' if the PDF file already exists, no need to re-create it
    If Not File.Exists(strPdfFile) Then
        Try
            startInfo.Arguments = "-fo """ & strSourceFileName & """ -pdf """ & strPdfFile & """"
            startInfo.FileName = g_strAppPath & "FO.NET\fonet.exe"
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

            Using proc As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)
                proc.WaitForExit()

                If proc.HasExited Then
                    proc.Dispose()
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "FormatObjectToPdf: " & ex.Message, ex)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Create PDF", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End Try
    End If

    ' wait 3 seconds to allow file to be released
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

    ' delete the source FO file when processing is complete
    If File.Exists(strSourceFileName) Then
        Try
            File.Delete(strSourceFileName)
        Catch iEx As IOException
            Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "Could not delete file '" & strSourceFileName & "': " & iEx.Message, iEx)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "Error deleting file '" & strSourceFileName & "': " & ex.Message, ex)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

The `FormatObjectToPdf` method is called from another method, `AsyncXmlToPdf`, which is actually where the `IOException` is thrown.  I had initially thought that the exception was in `FormatObjectToPdf` since that is where I am deleting the `.fo` file, so I had added a `Sleep(3000)` to see if giving it a few seconds would help.

Here is the `AsyncXmlToPdf`:

```
Public Sub AsyncXmlToPdf(ByVal state As Object)
    Dim intRxNo = state(0)
    Dim flgPrintResult As Boolean = state(1)
    Dim strFileName As String = g_strAppPath & intRxNo & ".fo"
    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim strPdfFile As String = g_strRootPath & "Paperwork\" & intRxNo & "M.pdf"

    Try
        If File.Exists(strPdfFile) Then
            File.Delete(strPdfFile)
        End If

        If Not File.Exists(strPdfFile) AndAlso Not File.Exists(strFileName) Then
            strOutput = XmlToFormatObject(intRxNo, g_strAppPath & "FO.NET\immfo.xsl")
            Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strFileName)
                writer.Write(strOutput)
            End Using

            Call FormatObjectToPdf(intRxNo, strFileName)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Call InsertLog("ErrorLog", "AsyncXmlToPdf: " & ex.Message, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The only part of either method other than the declaration of `strFileName` that even does anything with the `.fo` file is in `FormatObjectToPdf` and that method has a `Catch` block for `IOException`.  Why is the exception being caught in `AsyncXmlToPdf`??  Here is the actual error message:

`3/25/2015 11:15 AM: [IOException] AsyncXmlToPdf: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\1M2D4TCB.REJ\3LH3JZY2.TQC\<clickonce app>\561964.fo' because it is being used by another process.`

Everything works as expected, other than the occasional orphaned `.fo` file when this exception occurs.  Anyone have any suggestions on how I might be able to find out where the problem is?

Comment: `The only part of either method ... that even does anything with the .fo file is in FormatObjectToPdf`  it looks like `AsyncXmlToPdf` tries to open a StreamWriter on it.  If it is locked/in use that could cause the exception though I would expect that local catch to report it.  Maybe after the File.Exists test try to open it for Write in a new Try block and log the failure in the new Catch.  I'm not sure how to post a proper SO *answer* for a question asking for "suggestions"...unless it works I guess?

Comment: In `AsyncXmlToPdf`, I have the `StreamWriter` wrapped in a `Using` block, so I thought that would ensure that everything is properly released after exiting the `Using` block.  Also, I am only opening the `StreamWriter` if the file doesn't already exist, so as not to overwrite it.

Comment: Yes, it does not seem likely, but read the REMARKS section on MSDN about File.Exists - could something else be using/creating the same filename elsewhere?

Comment: I have finally been able to reproduce the issue on purpose.  If I click the button that starts that process multiple times in rapid succession, then I can get it to throw the exception.  I think I will have to disable the button and then re-enable it once the process is complete or some other event happens.  Thanks for the guidance @Plutonix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The only part of either method ... that even does anything with the .fo file is in FormatObjectToPdf`  It appears that `AsyncXmlToPdf` will also try to open a streamwriter on it.

If there is a chance that some other BackGroundWorker, Thread or Task could also be working on the same set of files, it would be possible for the same file to be in use in `AsyncXmlToPdf` and `FormatObjectToPdf`.  MSDN warns of this in the `File.Exists` entry:

> Be aware that another process can potentially do something with the file in between the time you call the Exists method and perform another operation on the file, such as Delete.

In your case it looks like it might be a a coin flip which method the Exception will happen in.

If an accidental double click could start the same process twice, it is possible that the same file could be in use in both methods at the same time.  You could add another test to see if you can open the file for ReadWrite.  Given that the file was not supposed to exist yet, you could at least be somewhat certain as to the reason.

Some sort of flag to prevent more than one set of jobs from starting might be the final solution.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I tried to get the process to run twice to force multiple threads to be trying to create/process the file simultaneously and figured out that is what was causing the issue.  My solution was to disable the button that starts the process until a different item is selected.